# How to prevent a nested list from being parsed as a string by Python's csv.reader?

Tags: python, csv, nested-lists

I have a nested list, like so:

```
[[['Mario', 100], ['Luigi', 100]], [['Donatello', 200]]]
```

Which I am trying to save to a CSV file like so:

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')

    for row in mylist:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

And then I read it like so:

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')

    for row in csv_reader:
        list_to_return.append(row)

return list_to_return
```

When I check myfile.csv, it looks like this:

```
['Mario', 100];['Luigi', 100]
['Donatello', 200]
```

However, when I read from myfile.csv, the list looks like this:

```
[["['Mario', 100]", "['Luigi', 100]"], ["['Donatello', 200]"]]
```

In other words, it seems the innermost list is parsed by the CSV reader as a string, and not a list.

I was wondering if any of you could help me with this. Why is the nested Python list parsed as a string by the CSV reader?

Comment: So how do you want to save the nested list?

Comment: CSV isn't a good format for nested lists. The writer takes each element of the row, in your case its still a list, and writes its string representation, with escapes for interior separators, to the file. If you want CSV, you need a way to flatten the lists. Otherwise, choose a different format like JSON to save the data.

Comment: Not following you Dani. I want the inner list to be a list object as well, not a string.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney for your helpful reply!

Comment: I will try to flatten the lists as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy as given here
Code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[['Mario', 100], ['Luigi', 100]], [['Donatello', 200]]])
print(a)

np.savez_compressed('myfile.npz', a=a)

arr_read = np.load('myfile.npz', allow_pickle=True)
arr_from_file = arr_read['a']
print(arr_from_file)
```

Output:

```
[list([['Mario', 100], ['Luigi', 100]]) list([['Donatello', 200]])]
[list([['Mario', 100], ['Luigi', 100]]) list([['Donatello', 200]])]
```